# Highcharts gem not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts, rubygems

I'm trying to create a line graph of weights for a user off of the lazy high charts gem.

I currently have in my `users_controller`

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @weights = Weight.where(user_id: @user.id)
  @weight_hash = @weights.to_json
  @chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
    f.title(:text => "Historical Weights")
    f.xAxis(:type => 'datetime', :title => {:text =>'Date'})  
    f.yAxis(:title => {:text => "pounds"})
    f.series(:name => 'Weight', :data => @weight_hash)
    f.chart({defaultSeriesType => 'line'})
  end
end
```

Within my weight model I have:

```
class Weight < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def as_json(*args)
   {
     :weight => self.weight,
     :date => self.date
   }
 end
end
```

Then in my users/show.html.erb I have

```
<%= high_chart("Weight", @chart) %>
```

but i'm getting the error

> undefined local variable or method `defaultSeriesType' for
>        #

I'm not sure how this method should be declared as it is part of the gem. Could anyone please explain what is going on?

Comment: after installing gem or passing gem into gemfile, did you bundle and restart the server ?

Comment: @7urkm3n yeah I put it in the gemfile and did "bundle install" and restarted a couple of times, I also added //= require highcharts/highcharts
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
//= require highcharts/highstock to application.js

Comment: is hat answer helped with `f.chart({:defaultSeriesType => 'line'})` ?

Comment: ah yep, I couldn't mark it as correct yet @7urkm3n thanks for looking at it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

`f.chart({defaultSeriesType => 'line'})`

It looks like you forgot to add a colon to `defaultSeriesType` to make it a symbol, so Ruby thinks it's a variable/method. Try changing it to:

`f.chart({:defaultSeriesType => 'line'})`

...like the other hashes.

Comment: Oh wow... you're right, I initially had everything written in the style of defaultSeriesType: 'line' and I messed it up in the process. That's pretty stupid. I thought I just didn't get what defaultSeriesType was.